# Buffered input in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What would be the proper way to do buffered input in ReactJS?

That is, you have a filter that narrows down (for example) an  element but after waiting for last user input to be *n* milliseconds ago.

Here's an example that you can paste to jsfiddle for example (it seems there is no "Share" functionality in for unregistered users?):

HTML:

```
<script src="https://facebook.github.io/react/js/jsfiddle-integration-babel.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
class Form extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Filter />
        <Options />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Filter extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleInputChange(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.value === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
    // Buffer user input somehow, so that if you write "test"
    // this would only log the value "test", instead of cumulatively:
    // t
    // te
    // tes
    // test

    // If I use setTimeout(), it simply makes the cumulative input take effect with a delay, but still "t", "te", "tes", "test" instead of just "test"
    console.log(value);

    // This is the use case:
    let elementsToHide = document.querySelectorAll("li:not([name*=" + value + "])");
    Object.keys(elementsToHide).map(function(el) {
      elementsToHide[el].style.visibility = "hidden";
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <input type="text" onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
    );
  }
}

class Options extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let examples = ["this", "is", "spartacus"];
    return (
      <ul>
        {
          examples.map(function(item) {
            return <li key={item} name={item}>{item}</li>
          })
        }
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Form />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Like I mention in the comments above, the input is cumulative. So if I write `test` then what it does is:

```
t
te
tes
test
```

But what I would like to happen is to buffer it first (eg. 1000 ms), and then just send:

`test`

Using `setTimeout()` simply delays when the cumulative data is sent

```
t    # appears after timeout
te   # appears after timeout
tes  # appears after timeout
test # appears after timeout
```

Comment: simple debounce

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of debounce from lodash

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
     this.handleInputChange= _.debounce(this.handleInputChange, n); // where n is the numnber of milliseconds you want to wait
}

handleInputChange = (event) => {
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.value === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;



    // This is the use case:
    let elementsToHide = document.querySelectorAll("li:not([name*=" + value + "])");
    Object.keys(elementsToHide).map(function(el) {
      elementsToHide[el].style.visibility = "hidden";
    });
  }
```